# Colisão ao gerar número aleatório que seja diferente de um número já inserido

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estou com o seguinte problema:
É necessário atribuir ao cliente um número de cupom para determinada pessoa após uma compra e ele tem as seguintes condições: deve possuir 6 dígitos, sendo que o primeiro dígito é a série do sorteio e os outros 5 são o número em si. Esses números não podem ser atribuídos em sequencia (000000, 000001, 000002, ...). O que consegui foi fazer um select para verificar se o número já existe na minha tabela como o exemplo de select abaixo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(1, LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 100000), 5, 0)) as num FROM oc_order WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT number_coupon, id_campaign FROM oc_campaign_coupon) as cc WHERE cc.number_coupon  = 'num' AND cc.id_campaign = '10') LIMIT 1
```

E faço a inserção desse valor que foi encontrado com o exemplo abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO oc_campaign_coupon SET id_customer = '1', id_campaign = '10', id_order = '60', number_coupon = (SELECT CONCAT(1, LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 100000), 5, 0)) as num FROM oc_order WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT number_coupon, id_campaign FROM oc_campaign_coupon) as cc WHERE cc.number_coupon  = 'num' AND cc.id_campaign = '10') LIMIT 1), created_at = NOW();
```

O problema ocorre que após 1000 mais ou menos ele começa a dar colisão na inserção, mesmo fazendo esse select. Teria outra opção de fazer isso é ter uma tabela com os números possíveis já inseridos e atribuir as campanhas e fazer um `rand()` para pegar alguma linha da tabela, porém cada campanha tem pelo menos 100 mil números e pode haver várias campanhas acontecendo ao mesmo tempo. Abaixo meu código que faço o `insert` e gera as colisões:

```
$select = "SELECT CONCAT(" . $this->db->escape($serie) . ", LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 100000), 5, 0)) as num FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT number_coupon, id_campaign FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_coupon) as cc WHERE cc.number_coupon  = 'num' AND cc.id_campaign = '" . $this->db->escape($campaign['id']) . "') LIMIT 1";

$sql = "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign_coupon SET id_customer = '" . $this->db->escape($sellercoupon['customer_id']) . "', id_campaign = '" . $this->db->escape($campaign['id']) . "', id_order = '" . $this->db->escape($sellercoupon['order_id']) . "', number_coupon = (" . $select . "), created_at = NOW();";

$this->db->query($sql);
```

Alguém teria um dica de como fazer de uma outra forma ou caso minha `query` estiver algo errado.

Obs: Já troquei de `NOT EXISTS` para `NOT IN` e ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: acho que vai precisar fazer um lock da tabela se quiser garantir que verificou o num e inseriu antes de outro processo fazer isso

Comment: seria necessário adicionar o LOOK TABLES antes de cada insert? Ex. LOCK TABLES oc_campaign_coupon READ; SELECT * FROM oc_campaign_coupon?

Comment: Fiz esse LOCK TABLES para minha query e ainda gera duplicatas de valores:
LOCK TABLES oc_order READ, oc_campaign_coupon as cc READ, oc_campaign_coupon as occ READ,  oc_campaign_coupon WRITE;
INSERT INTO oc_campaign_coupon SET id_customer = '1', id_campaign = '10', id_order = '60', 
number_coupon = (SELECT CONCAT(1, LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 100000), 5, 0)) as num 
FROM oc_order WHERE 'num' NOT IN 
(SELECT number_coupon FROM (SELECT number_coupon, id_campaign FROM oc_campaign_coupon as occ) as cc 
WHERE cc.id_campaign = '10') LIMIT 1), created_at = NOW();
UNLOCK TABLES;

Comment: olha, não basta fazer lock e gerar um aleatório e verificar se existe, precisa por isso por exemplo numa function, que verifique se existe dentro de um loop, se existir gera outro e assim por diante... vai ficar mais lento conforme a tabela for enchendo, mas é o jeito. se a performance ficar ruim com o tempo, pode pensar num algoritmo mais inteligente, mas precisa gerar o valor e verificar, se já existir, gerar novamente

Comment: Eu faria uma tabela do tipo id,sequencia , a sequencia seria de 00001 a 99999 já embaralhada sem repetição , a aplicação , pegaria o menor id usaria a sequencia e deletaria o id , seria rápida.

Comment: pensei em fazer dessa forma, porém pode ter várias campanhas de sorteio rolando, então teria que existir várias tabelas com essa sequencia.

Comment: uma tabela (idcampanha,id,seq) mas a solução de gerar e testar a colisão tb funciona , uso Oracle e onde trabalho temos uma solução assim.Eu pediria para a chave ser maior ou alfanumérica menos chance de colidir.

Comment: entendi, mudei para gerar e testar se tem colisão mesmo